# How to create a shared buffer of a value from the command line in C (producer/consumer multi-threading problem)?

Tags: c, operating-system, initialization, producer-consumer

I get the size of a buffer to be created from the command line with this code:

```
while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "d:p:t:b:")) != -1)
    switch (c) {
    case 'd':
      root_dir = optarg;
      break;
    case 'p':
      port = atoi(optarg);
      break;
    case 't':
      // NUMBER OF CONSUMER THREADS
      n_threads = atoi(optarg);
      break;
    case 'b':
      // BUFFER SIZE
      THREAD_BUFFER_SIZE = atoi(optarg);
    default:
      fprintf(stderr, "usage: wserver [-d basedir] [-p port] [-t threads] [-b buffer] \n");
      exit(1);
    }
```

Which is contained in my main() function.

Lets say I execute `./wserver -d . -p 8004 -t 8 -b 10`.
I expect to get a buffer of size 10.

This buffer is being shared between producer and consumer threads, whose function implementations lie outside of the main() function. With that, I receive an error stating 'buffer is undeclared.'

I then created a buffer of default size, lets say 4 (`int buffer[4];`), outside of the main function so that it would be declared. Then inside of the main() function, I add `buffer = buffer[THREAD_BUFFER_SIZE]`, which gets the size requested from the getopt case statement above. Which is obviously wrong, but I do not understand how to replace this code to allow the shared buffer of a size requested to be created.

Any tips?

Default initialized buffer on line 3 and shared buffer commented:

```
char default_root[] = ".";
int count = 0;
int buffer[10];

void *producer(void *THREAD_BUFFER_SIZE) {
  [uses buffer]
}

void *consumer(void *arg) {
  [uses buffer]
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int c;
  char *root_dir = default_root;
  int port = 10000;

  // I created these
  int n_threads;
  int THREAD_BUFFER_SIZE;
  pthread_t* mythreads; // consumer threads
  pthread_t p_id; // producer thread
    
  while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "d:p:t:b:")) != -1)
    switch (c) {
    case 'd':
      root_dir = optarg;
      break;
    case 'p':
      port = atoi(optarg);
      break;
    case 't':
      // NUMBER OF CONSUMER THREADS
      n_threads = atoi(optarg);
      break;
    case 'b':
      // BUFFER SIZE
      THREAD_BUFFER_SIZE = atoi(optarg);
    default:
      fprintf(stderr, "usage: wserver [-d basedir] [-p port]\n");
      exit(1);
    }

  // SHARED BUFFER
  buffer = buffer[THREAD_BUFFER_SIZE];

  // Create producer thread
  if (pthread_create(&p_id, NULL, producer, (void*) THREAD_BUFFER_SIZE) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "unable to create producer thread\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  // Create n_threads consumer threads
  mythreads = (pthread_t*) malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*n_threads);
  for(int i = 0; i < n_threads; i++) {
    if(pthread_create(&mythreads[i], NULL, consumer, NULL) != 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "unable to create consumer thread\n");
      exit(1);
    }
  }


  // run out of this directory
  chdir_or_die(root_dir);

  // now, get to work
  int listen_fd = open_listen_fd_or_die(port);
  while (1) {
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
    int client_len = sizeof(client_addr);
    int conn_fd = accept_or_die(listen_fd, (sockaddr_t *) &client_addr,
                (socklen_t *) &client_len);
    request_handle(conn_fd);
    close_or_die(conn_fd);
  }

  // Added at end to close and clean
  pthread_join(p_id, NULL);
  free(mythreads);
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&mut);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: *With that, I receive an error stating 'buffer is undeclared.'* - it is not only undeclared, it is even unmentioned in the presented code. Please post [mcve].

Comment: @EugeneSh. I added my main code along with the buffer initialization prior.

Comment: `buffer = buffer[THREAD_BUFFER_SIZE];` - this is not a valid C code to allocate arrays dynamically. And it is really unrelated to the fact it is supposed to be shared or not.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I am aware that it is not valid C code. However, I am looking for a way to do this correctly in which my producer/consumer methods will recognize a buffer at the requested size: THREAD_BUFFER_SIZE, but I cannot create this buffer anywhere besides my main() function.

Comment: You can't. You can pass the size as a parameter to your threads though. Or make it a part of a structure. Don't forget to protect it from concurrent access.